# Experimental conclusions about slope, derivative, values using the graphical representation of a certain function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> The graph below shows a differentiable function f(x) on the domain [0, 5].

[image: image of graph]

> *Question A:* Which is greater:

> f '(1) **vs**  $$\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{2-1}$$

> *Question B:* Which is greater:     f '(1) **vs** f(1)

Thinking:

Question A:  So I calculated the fraction to get f (1). I think f '(1) is greater based on the graph because f '(1) is steeper (slope of tangent.

Question B:  So I think f '(1) is greater than f (1) because of the graph steep.

Please help - am I right?

Comment: A: This is difficult to say without knowing the value of $f(2)$. 

B: $f(1) = 0$ as I can see while $f'(1) > 0$ as there is a steep slope around $x=1$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "So I calculated the fraction **to get f (1).**" The fraction doesn't give you $f(1)$...

Comment: @JeanMarie I minus the numerator and denominator to get f(1)/1.  I assumed you cancel out the 1s to get f(1).

Comment: No ! it's false : here in this case, the slope $(f(2)-f(1))/(2-1)$ of the line segment joining $(1,f(1))$ and $(2,f(2))$ which is, say, 3, cannot be equal to $f(1)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean that you simply have to look at the graph and notice that the slope of the line connecting $(1,f(1))$ and $(2,f(2))$ is steeper than the tangent line to the function at $x=1$ (this is actually $f'(1)$). Therefore $f'(1)$ is bigger.

Comment: You probably mean that the slope of the line is less steep than the tangent?